# Run launcher app in safe mode of android

Tags: android, android-launcher, safe-mode, app-launcher

I had implemented one launcher app for tab. This app is working good in normal mode but issue in safe mode. I am not able to set my app as launcher app in safe mode. Can anyone tell me how i can run my app as launcher app in safe mode.

Possible solutions is

1. Run my app as Launcher app.
2. Disable safe mode feature of android.
3. If device will go in safe mode, then ask password first to open this device.

If anyone knows better solution from above,please mention in comment. but i need this launcher app to be run in safe mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't. The safe mode is designed to load built-in apps only

Answer (score 0):

Only system apps run in safe mode. All the apps installed by the user doest not work..and there is a reason for that.

I think your ultimate goal is to create a kiosk mode. Where you want to restrict the user. You can two things:

- If you are providing the mobile device you can use COSU from android 6.0 and above where there are APIs to disable safe mode. To access these apis your app needs to be the device owner.
- You can access APIs to read UI contents of other apps and enforce clicks on them. To read other apps and enforce click you need to get special permission([Accessibility](https://github.com/bunnyblue/ApkAutoInstaller)). Using this you can auto install apps, disable dialogs..